# Bash scripting: mkdir error

Tags: bash, quotes, sh, mkdir

I have the following script sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Aborts the script on "simple command failure" (does not cover pipes)
set -e

# Makes sure we do not run the script outside the correct directory (i.e. the backup directory)
projects_directory='~/projects' 
backup_drectory="${projects_directory}/backup/"
echo "Backup directory: ${backup_drectory}"

if [ ! -d "$projects_directory" ]; then 
    mkdir "$projects_directory"
    echo "${projects_directory} created successfully" 
fi
```

Which fails miserably with the following output:

```
Backup directory: ~/projects/backup/
mkdir: cannot create directory `~/projects': No such file or directory
```

I do not understand why. If I enter the `mkdir ~/projects` command manually in a Terminal, the directory gets created. Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Try to replace the ~ with your absolute home directory (/home/username/). Which user executes your backup script (are you using a cron job?)

Comment: I am planning to use cron, yes. So far I am testing it manually via Terminal. 
Your solution works. Could you explain to me why ? 
Is ther any workaround so I do not have to hardcode the user path into the script ?

Comment: Shell quoting is your enemy. You can read about how the shell handles single versus double quotes here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: the answer given by lanzz is correct. Make sure to start the script by the correct user (using crontab -e from the users shell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the single quotes:

```
projects_directory=~/projects
```

The quoting prevents the shell from expanding the `~` character.

Comment: Thanks ! Beginner's mistake ;)

Comment: +1. I also recommend using `mkdir -p` (make parent directories as needed).

Comment: Thanks x2! So I do not need to check for `~/projects` existence, I can directly issue `mkdir -p ~/projects/backup`. You made my day sir !